# how to pass database values in Yii2 Highchart

Tags: highcharts, yii2

I'm trying to create chart using Yii2 and highchart widget from [this](https://github.com/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts/) repository

This is my Highchart's code:

```
echo Highcharts::widget([
        'scripts' => [
            'highcharts-more',   
            'modules/exporting', 
            'themes/grid' 
        ],
        'options' => [
          'title' => ['text' => NULL],
          'xAxis' => ['categories' => $chart_x_axis],
          'yAxis' => ['title' => ['text' => 'Income']],
          'series' => $data_series, 
          'credits' => ['enabled' => false],
        ],
    ]);
```

First, I create data series manually :

```
$data_series = array(
    array(
        'name'=>'February',
        'data'=>array(10000,20000,3000),
    ),array(
        'name'=>'November',
        'data'=>array(20000,10000),
    ),array(
        'name'=>'December',
        'data'=>array(20500),
    )
);
```

and here's the result :

```
=================Json Format : 
[{"name":"February","data":[10000,20000,3000]},{"name":"November","data":[20000,10000]},{"name":"December","data":[20500]}]
 ================= Array Format : 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => February
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10000
                    [1] => 20000
                    [2] => 3000
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => November
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 20000
                    [1] => 10000
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => December
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 20500
                )

        )

)
```

Highchart show **Normally**:
But when I try to load from models with the same result with above :

```
=================Json Format : 
[{"name":"February","data":["3000","10000","20000"]},{"name":"November","data":["10000","20000"]},{"name":"December","data":["20500"]}]
 ================= Array Format : 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => February
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3000
                    [1] => 10000
                    [2] => 20000
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => November
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10000
                    [1] => 20000
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => December
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 20500
                )

        )

)
```

Data series are not showing. Can anyone help me where wrong is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, this is my stupidity.
This issue has been solved [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/yii.indonesia/permalink/10153910570379673/?comment_id=10153910806514673).

I don't know highcart accept INTEGER data type, so I change my code from :

```
foreach ($months as $m)
{
    $_data_series[] = $m["omset_nominal"];
}
```

Into :

```
foreach ($months as $m)
{
    $_data_series[] = (int)$m["omset_nominal"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model create method :

```
public method getData(){
   $data_series = array(
    array(
        'name'=>'February',
        'data'=>array(10000,20000,3000),
    ),array(
        'name'=>'November',
        'data'=>array(20000,10000),
    ),array(
        'name'=>'December',
        'data'=>array(20500),
    )
);

return  $data_series;
}
```

In your view

```
use use app\models\highchart;
echo Highcharts::widget([
        'scripts' => [
            'highcharts-more',   
            'modules/exporting', 
            'themes/grid' 
        ],
        'options' => [
          'title' => ['text' => NULL],
          'xAxis' => ['categories' => $chart_x_axis],
          'yAxis' => ['title' => ['text' => 'Income']],
          'series' => $highchar->getData, 
          'credits' => ['enabled' => false],
        ],
    ]);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, your code is only moving static in controller, into models :)

Comment: What I need is, load data series from database into highchart data series

Comment: then you should ask question properly.

Comment: I'm sorry for make you confused with my question @Amitesh :)